# java convert resultset to a list

Tags: java, resultset

I want to convert my Resultset to List of object . This is my query:

```
 String querystring1= "SELECT userID, privilege"
               + "FROM dbo.User order by userID, privilege";


 userID  privilege
 ------------------
 1001    read 
 1001   write
 1001   execute 
 1001   delete
 1006    execute 
 1006    read
 1006    write
 1007   read
 1007    write
```

I have a class User defined like :

```
public class User {
   private int userID;
   private List<String> userPrivelege;
}
```

I want to have as an output to a list of Users, and this is my implemented code:

```
   String previousId = null;  
   List<String> PrivList= new ArrayList<String>();
   List<User> allUserList= new ArrayList<User>();

   while(result_set.next()) {
      String userID = result_set.getString("userID");
      String privilege = result_set.getString("privilege");
      if (previousId == null) { // first time
         User user = new User();
         PrivList.add(privilege);
         previousId=userID;
      } else if (previousId.equals(userID) {
         PrivList.add(privilege);
      } else {
         user.setUserPrivilege(PrivList);
         allUserList.add(user);
         PrivList.clear();
         previousId=null;
      }
   }
```

The problem is,  other than the first user object created, all the next one are always missing the first value which means user 1006 will have 2 privileges other than 3.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you need to stick to jdbc ? Using an ORM will do the job for you. Additionnaly, the way you tackle this problem means your code depends on your query (spec. orderby), have you thought about that ?

Comment: @Laurent B: using an ORM at the actual state of the project will be a problem because there will be many changes to do.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers and discussions on this. I got it. I made the change and got the result as expected.

Comment: Don't deserve a downvote(+1). It is a question very correctly expressed with all information required to address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `PrivList`  for each user.

Additionnaly, you need to add a privilege for the next user, otherwise you lose that information on the loop.

Edits shown by the `<--` comments.

```
while(result_set.next()) {
    String userID = result_set.getString("userID");
    String privilege = result_set.getString("privilege");
    if (previousId == null) { // first time
        User user = new User();
        PrivList.add(privilege);
        previousId=userID;
    } else if (previousId.equals(userID) {
        PrivList.add(privilege);
    } else { 
        // nex user
        user.setUserPrivilege(PrivList);
        allUserList.add(user);
        PrivList = new ArrayList<>();  // <--
        PrivList.add(privilege);       // <--
        previousId=null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All  `User` objects refer the same object `List` of privileges as you don't create a new instance for each User. Instead you clear only the List.
Consequently, all Users are set with 2 privileges as the last User that you handle has 2 privileges.

So replace :

```
 PrivList.clear();
```

by :

```
 PrivList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because You Miss the First privilege of the New User here,

```
  else {
             user.setUserPrivilege(PrivList);
             allUserList.add(user);
             PrivList.clear();
             previousId=null;
    }
```

Do the privilege initialization for the next user here.

`PrivList = new ArrayList<>();
PrivList.add(privilege);`

Answer (score 2):

- As far as I can see, you are never assigning the user ID to the `User` object?
- `PrivList.clear();` clears the list that you have just assigned to a user. Instead create a new list, as davidxxx also said.
- As anchreg said, after you have created a user and added it to the list, you need to initialize the next user in the same way as you did the first time.
- After your loop terminates, if `previousId` is not `null` (that is, any user previlege was processed at all), you need to assign values to the last user and add it to the list in the same way as in the last `else` case in the loop.

All of this said a more elegant solution could be coded using streams.

Answer (score 1):

In m y opinion, I think that is not a good model. You should have a second table with privileges related with an user. But to solve your question:

```
List<String> privList= new ArrayList<String>();
Map<Integer, List<String>> hmUserPrivileges = HashMap<Integer, String>();

while(result_set.next()) {
    int userID = result_set.getInt("userID");
    String privilege = result_set.getString("privilege");

    if (!hmUserPrivileges.contains(userID)) {
        privList= new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    privList.add(privilege);
    hmUserPrivileges.put(userID, privList);
}

List<User> allUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> iterator = hmUserPrivileges.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry = iterator.next();
    User user = new User()

    user.setUserID(entry.getKey());
    user.setUserPrivelege(entry.getValue());

    allUserList.add(user);
}
```